# Can we create Reusable Logic Apps or any Alternate Solution?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to create Reusable Logic Apps is that possible or any alternate solution?

Thanks in advance!

Saan.

Comment: Please provide more details, what do you mean Reusable?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Logic App, wrap it in an ARM template with parameters, e.g. environment details, and then use PowerShell to deploy it multiple times.

[Create and deploy logic apps with Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates)